# Give read and write permissons of WebPart to specific users

Tags: sharepoint-online, web-part

I have thousands of users in my sharepoint online, I create a list and publish as a WebPart, now all my users have access to that list, I want to know how can I only give access at certain persons of all my users. Is that possible?

Answer (score 2):

If you are using a ListViewWebPart to display a list, you can use Audience Targeting to hide it and provide permissions to certain user groups.  [This Artical](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Target-content-to-specific-audiences-33d84cb6-14ed-4e53-a426-74c38ea32293) will help you set it up.

Answer (score 2):

Permissions for users / groups exist at the following levels. Site > Apps(lists/libraries) > Items(folders/documents).

With that said web parts are copies of existing Apps on your site that can inherit permissions from the site or have broken permissions made to be unique for that app and the items below it. With that said web parts inherit permissions from the app they relate to.

if you have a page with web parts you can use a special web part setting called *audience targeting* to make a specific web part only visible to the audiences you add to the audience targeting.

let me know if this clears anything up

SharePoint permissions: 
https://support.office.com/en-US/article/Understanding-permission-levels-in-SharePoint-87ecbb0e-6550-491a-8826-c075e4859848

Audience targeting:
https://support.office.com/en-US/article/Target-content-to-specific-audiences-33D84CB6-14ED-4E53-A426-74C38EA32293

Comment: I create a group in my sharepoint, how can I assign that group to my list?

Comment: List Settings > Permissions > (Then break inheritance so the permissions stop inheriting from the site, this will leave a copy of the site permissions on the site but they will no longer automatically be in sync with changes made to the parent permissions). Next Add your "new" group to the permissions of the list though the "add new user/group" ribbon command. This video also may help: https://support.office.com/en-US/article/Video-Understanding-permissions-in-SharePoint-c13a4f37-eea1-48f6-8dac-14ac37d73903